# android app and test apk: version conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android studio 3.0.1: create new project

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

```
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in 
project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1)
differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html 
for details.
```

Will the versions not be automatically resolved to the higher version? 
This is completely new project created by android studio.

```
   com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
        \ com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1

   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        \ com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `annotation` ground from espresso:

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   }
```